Can I use a PublicTrust Certificate created with Trusted Signing to sign an MSIX package in Visual Studio?
I need to sign an MSIX I'm creating for a .NET Framework 4.X Windows Forms application. What is the process for doing that once I create the certificate? Is it stored in an Azure Key Vault and do I use the wizard in VS to get it from there? Or do I download a file? Or...? We're waiting on our Identity Validation, so we can't actually try it out yet, but are trying to be ready.

The process to provision your information can be found here in-depth, you can skip right to the create a certificate profile step. But like you said, you are still awaiting public trust identity validation. You could potentially test using a private trust model
Regarding where is the certificate store, it's not on an AKV, its stored on an hsm.
